# Blazor publish integrity issue

Tags: iis, azure-devops, blazor, blazor-webassembly

My team is currently working on a new Blazor app and we are facing some strange behavior. We deploy our APP using Azure Dev Ops, but it seems that sometimes things go wrong. If we deploy the same version with the the same pipeline, the issue could be solved...

This is the error we (sometimes) get in every browser chrome, firefox, edge, ...:

```
admin:1 Failed to find a valid digest in the 'integrity' attribute for resource 'https://domain/_framework/dotnet.timezones.blat' with computed SHA-256 integrity '47DEQpj8HBSa+/TImW+5JCeuQeRkm5NMpJWZG3hSuFU='. The resource has been blocked.
```

This seems to be happening completely random. We have tried everything... like disabling compression, checking IIS settings, clearing cache, ... We also read the complete Microsoft Documentation. Some other guys also had this problem and they have a solution by clearing the obj/ folder. But we never have this issue locally... So this isn't a solution for us.

Does anybody have any idea what could be the problem? Because it seems completely random to us so far.

The app is ASP.NET core hosted and not stand-alone.

Any help would be very much appreciated!

Kind regards,

Evert

Comment: It is difficult to reproduce your problem based on your description, I suggest you open a case via: https://support.microsoft.com.

Answer (score 3):

I just ran into the exact same problem. My VS solution compiled and ran under VS 2022 no problem. But when I published to my dev or prod web server I got the same message that you encountered. I solved it by clearing the **bin, obj, and .config** folders in all my projects in the solution. You mentioned that you don't have the problem locally -- neither did I and this still resolved the issue when I deployed. I suspect an older version of a file is getting into the deployment pipeline somewhere. Mine is also a hosted solution under .NET 6.0.2.

Comment: It worked with just deleting bin, obj folders.